# How do I update a cells value based on filtered data in a different sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set sample size that doesn't update when a field is filtered. I want the sample size to be dynamic with the data that it is correlated with. The problem is, how do I check if the index of this sheets field A1 (or even A221 depending on the filter) has a column that says TRUE exactly where another sheets column says TRUE?

Here's a pic of the total sample size of Lease, Own, and Total-
[image: Sample Size]

I want those numbers to be dynamic based on filtered criteria.

[image: Filtered by Occupation]

Note how the row indices are updated (and they won't always be in order, this is only because they are in alphabetical order).

Here's an image of the table I'm working with. I figured that an `=OR` would combine all of the rows into one where all the `TRUE` values need to be in there. That will be my subset.

[image: TRUTH TABLE]

Comment: Maybe Subtotal function could work, but I don't understand  what you’re trying to achieve

Comment: Subtotal isn't working alone. The problem is that although someone likes baseball, they may also like soccer, and that is not 2 different people, it's one person. How do I account for that?

Comment: Some sample data would really improve this question.

Comment: Can you add a helper column?  (Using Subtotal you can add a formula to indicate filter visibility for each row.  Then use SumIfS to get your totals)

Comment: Updated the question. I might be on to something with the `=OR` function but I still need to be able to combine rows that are filtered on a different sheet.